# Redirect several log files in docker container to stdout (legacy application)

Tags: bash, shell, logging, docker

I have to put legacy application into Docker container. The app is running fine but I cannot display all the log files. The problem is that the app is creating several log files (e.g. `service.log, license.log, security.log` etc.) AFTER starting the executable.

I have a starting script (let's call it `start.sh`) which prepares some things (links, config) and then starts the app which creates the mentioned log files.

After some googling I have found [similar problem](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19616) and try to apply the solution that uses named pipes (creating link to `/proc/1/fd/1` did not worked). So I placed the following in the starting script:

```
mkfifo /path/to/app/license.log && tail -f /path/to/app/license.log &
mkfifo /path/to/app/security.log && tail -f /path/to/app/security.log &
...
```

but the problem is that only FIRST file will be redirected to `docker logs`. The others are not visible at all.

The curious thing is that in `start.sh` I have a line `source before_start.sh` which executes some specific commands depending on environment. Placing the `mkfifo license.log` in the `start.sh` and the  `mkfifo service.log` in the `before_start.sh` works.
The problem is that I have more files and do not want to `source` all of them.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is a legacy application we still have to have the log files in place. In that case the solution that works for me is to create the files by `touch` and read them using tail:

```
touch /path/to/app/logfile.log && tail -f /path/to/app/logfile.log &
```

So replacing `mkfifo` with `touch` solved my problem.